# installing `gdebi` But Getting Error ` linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-76-generic but it is not going to be installed`

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

trying to install `gdebi` but not be able to install. Please help

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdebi : Depends: gdebi-core (= 0.9.5.7ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: gksu but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-76-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-70-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-70-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-70-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-76-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-76-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-76-generic but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

i have also tried to use `apt-get -f install` but its also not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem by removing old kernels from my system. 
for more information please read [how to remove old kernels](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels)